# Deflector add on for 4" led recessed light / wall wash / highlight or need to replace?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, led

In my front entryway I have built-in nooks with recessed 4" led downlights inside the nook. I finally decorated the nooks and I want to keep lights on the lowest dimmer setting throughout the day to highlight the nooks and what we are displaying.

The current setup works well, but even on the dimmest setting a lot of light leaks out into the house in way that is distracting. I really just want to focus the light into the area ( wall wash ?), almost diffused and less bright then even the lowest dimmer setting.

My current lights are all-in-one - light fixture with trim. I can't seem to find, but wondering if I am not using the right terms, some type of "deflector" that covers up half of the light. I was hoping for something that just snaps on/over the existing all-in-one. I think I saw some trim options, but they look like they are for a setup where the trim and lightbulb are not one integrated thing.

Is this possible, or is the only option to replace the lights all together with a different all in one light meant for angles on a gimble? Since this is a high visibility area I don't want to do anything hacky/DIY like duct taping half the light (probably not even safe?).

If I do need to replace, what is the name of the type of connector for my current lights, so I can find one that matches - or do I need to replace the box connected to the mains fully?

Where the light is:
[image: photo of the nook with the downlight]

Connector from light to box:
[image]

Label on light itself:
[image]

Box connecting led light to the mains:
[image: photo of label on the box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is **wall wash trim** (or at least I find things that match my thought of what you are describing with that search term) but that trim normally does go in a standard "can light" fixture, so unless your light manufacturer makes a compatible product (unlikely - the better way to do that with LED is to make a fixture that only lights the area desired, not cut off half the light the fixture puts out) you're going to have to replace the fixtures.

Normally the ballast and light are primarily sold together and compatible with each other. You MIGHT be able to find another fixture compatible with your LED ballast, but it's not a given.

A quick looks finds mostly other shapes of fixture (linear seems common) for dedicated LED wall washers. *I've not made an extensive search as shopping for you is not really the point - you know what you're looking for and can make your own choices from what's available.*

*You might want to consider motion sensors for the lights - they will fade your* objet de art *fabrics and waste energy running all day while nobody is around to look at them.)*

Comment: thanks does ballast mean the connection point or something different? The summary here is I likely need to replace everything from the mains with whatever comes in the kit,; that should technically just be like changing any other traditional fixture?

Comment: "Ballast" is the box (LED Driver) between the light and the mains. The terminology comes from the previous "non-directly mains powered" lights, florescent tubes. That lists the fixtures it's compatible with, so I guess you could see if any of those suit your desired look. But it's likely that they are sold with the driver, not separate, so it's unlikely to save you anything.

Comment: Or replace the fixture with an eyeball style, where you can direct the "beam" more towards the wall.

Comment: @Huesmann what is the actual difference tradeoff - e.g., I just looked up eyeball and the "angle" is bigger than one of the gimble ones. Is is that the light is smaller / less watts even given the same angle?

Comment: @HelpEric the trim covers a portion of the light.  If you simply redirect the light (as an eyeball) you get the same amount of light, just in a different direction.  It really depends what you're looking to do.